# Discord.net | How can I turn the user ID's that belong to people in my database to usernames which I can use for my leaderboard?

Tags: c#, bots, discord, leaderboard, discord.net

I'm making a leaderboard for the leveling system my Discord bot has. The list will make a list of the people with most XP and order them from highest to lowest amount. I have already achieved this goal, but I can only show to user's ID next to their XP amount in the leaderboard. How can I turn this user ID into a username?

```
foreach (ulong n in DbContext.Experiences.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.XP).Select(x => x.ID))
{
    Context.Guild.GetUser(n).ToString()
}

var leaderboard = string.Concat(DbContext.Experiences.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.XP).Select(x => $"Level {x.LevelNumber} with {x.XP} xp 
    {//username must be here}\n"));

await ReplyAsync(leaderboard.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments in code:

```cs
//What exactly is this for loop meant to do? 
//You appear to be getting a user based on ID and doing nothing with that value.
//This should be removed
foreach (ulong n in DbContext.Experiences.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.XP).Select(x => x.ID))
{
   //While this is how to get a user by ID, you aren't actually doing anything with this once it's retrieved.
    Context.Guild.GetUser(n).ToString()
}

//You can simply fetch the username here, given that you have access to the ID
var leaderboard = string.Concat(DbContext.Experiences.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.XP).Select(x => $"Level {x.LevelNumber} with {x.XP} xp 
    {//username must be here}\n"));

await ReplyAsync(leaderboard.ToString());
```

Your modified code should look something like:

```cs
var leaderboard = string.Join("\n", DbContext.Experiences
                                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.XP)
                                             .Select(x => $"Level {x.LevelNumber} with {x.XP} xp {Context.Guild.GetUser(x.ID).ToString()}"));
await ReplyAsync(leaderboard);
```

NOTE: I've replaced `string.Concat` with `string.Join` as it's a more efficient String building method.

Answer (score 1):

What I would expect to see (Never looked at Discord if that's where the database structure comes from) would be a table for:

- Guild
- Experiences
- Users

I would Expect dbContext.Users to have something like:

```
UserId | UserName
```

and then a Guilds table to have something like:

```
GuildId | GuildName | UserId
```

and Experiences to look something like:

```
ExperienceId | UserId
```

I'll continue to make some assumptions here:

```
Context.Guild.GetUser(n).ToString();
```

This to me looks like the an EF Core query which translates into SQL:

```
select UserId from Guild
```

Working from that, I see a few potential issues:

First, the Guild method returning only a string or long is weird. Return an object if that's your implementation.

More importantly, you can do this likely in 1 query:

in Sql:

```
Select g.GuildId, e.Experiece, u.UserId, u.UserName from Guild g
   left join Users u on g.UserId = u.UserId
   left join Experiences e on u.UserId = e.UserId
where g.GuildId = @myGuildId
order by e.Experience Desc
```

this would give you back rows like:
   1 | 1500 | 10 | BitesSpoons
   1 | 1450 | 51 | LostElbows
   1 | 1121 | 98 | EarthSkyFire
   1 | 990  | 15 | GoldenGoose

What I would do: Create a view class, and map it either with something like AutoMapper from a query, or when you materialize the instance:

Make a class:

```
public class LeaderView 
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public long UserId {get; set;}
    public long GuildId {get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
}
```

And then a linq to Sql query like:

```
var leaders = from g in context.Guilds
join u in context.Users on g.UserId = u.UserId
join e in context.Experience on u.UserId  = e.UserId
select new LeaderView
{
    UserName = u.UserName,
    UserId = u.UserId,
    GuildId = g.UserId,
    Experience = e.Experience
};  

leaders = leaders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Experience);
return leaders.ToList();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you're assuming I have the usernames stored in the database, which I have not. I already know how to get everyone's user ID, but I am looking to turn those user ID's into usernames.
I can, however, select the first person on the list and get his username with this: `Context.Guild.GetUser(INSERT_ID)`
But I am looking to do this for everyone on the list, and use the result in a message.

Comment: I am. And is context not a database context? I Made a ton of assumptions not being familiar with discord

Comment: Yeah, DbContext is a database context. However I don't have the usernames stored in the database (or else it would be very simple haha).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the desired User ID

`Context.Guild.GetUser(THE_USER_ID_HERE).Username`
This return the user's username if exists.

If your leaderboard is global (where the user might not be in the server in which the command is executed)
 you can use `client.GetUser(THE_USER_ID_HERE).Username` instead, where `client` is your bot's current socket client.

(Or alternatively, access the `Nickname` property if you wish to display the user's name tied to the server instead)

Comment: I've tried this before and it works for one user. But I want it to get everyone's username, with only having their ID as reference.

Comment: @VACEfron then loop through the list of their IDs, then fetch their usernames with the specified method (Passing it into a list to let you do what you want with it, or add it to the stringbuilder if you are planning to print out all of the user's name).